How to create TextureView programmatically with ExoPlayer in .NET/MAUI?
Goal
I am trying to create an ExoPlayer using Android code within .NET (MAUI) that renders to a TextureView (rather than the default SurfaceView).
Background
This is discussed in terms of Android in this thread.
In .NET/MAUI we have the following constructor which would apply for the ExoPlayer:
public unsafe StyledPlayerView (global::Android.Content.Context? context, global::Android.Util.IAttributeSet? attrs)
So you could run this as:
var PlayerView = new StyledPlayerView(androidContext, attributes); 
//presuming you have a working 'attributes' file...

The second 'attributes' argument global::Android.Util.IAttributeSet? attrs is where we are supposed to specify we want a TextureView.
From the link above, we must pass in an XML file which is first converted into the IAttributeSet object to specify the TextureView as a target surface.
An example XML given is:
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
     android:id="@+id/player_view"
     app:surface_type="texture_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

The XML file of this nature must be converted into the attribute needed for the constructor by:
val xmlAttributes = context.resources.getXml(R.xml.player_view).let {
    try {
        it.next()
        it.nextTag()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // do something, log, whatever
    }
    Xml.asAttributeSet(it)
}

Question
If I want to work completely in a C# script, and I want to have no XML files to load from anywhere, but rather want to just declare this minimal short XML snippet as a string or written in my C# code directly, can I do this?
Can I then pass that into the code for creating the attribute? Or alternatively, can we make the IAttributeSet for the constructor directly in C# without even bothering with creating the XML first?
My Best Attempt
My best attempt shown provides an error which I don't understand.
In Visual Studio 2022, if one goes:

File > New > Android Application
Add the ExoPlayer NuGet Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer
Then in MainActivity.cs, one can try the following code:

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    string xmlString =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
        "<Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.UI.PlayerView " +           
        "android:id=\"@+id/player_view\" " +
        "app:surface_type=\"texture_view\" " + //KEY NEEDED LINE FOR GOAL
        "android:layout_width=\"match_parent\" " +
        "android:layout_height=\"match_parent\"/>";
    
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString));
    xmlReader.Read();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("XML READER " + xmlReader.AttributeCount);
            
    Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributes = Android.Util.Xml.AsAttributeSet(xmlReader);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ATTRIBUTES " + attributes.AttributeCount);
    
    Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.UI.StyledPlayerView styledPlayerView = new(this, attributes);            

Issues
No errors are given in Visual Studio on coding. However two problems are evident on running it:

If you attempt to debug out the xmlReader with the following code, it says **System.Xml.XmlException:** ''android' is an undeclared prefix. Line 2, position 52.':

while (xmlReader.Read()) {
    switch (xmlReader.NodeType) {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<{0}>", xmlReader.Name);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<![CDATA[{0}]]>", xmlReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<?{0} {1}?>", xmlReader.Name, xmlReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<!--{0}-->", xmlReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Document:
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE {0} [{1}]", xmlReader.Name, xmlReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xmlReader.Name);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("</{0}>", xmlReader.Name);
            break;
    }
}

Debug taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.read?view=net-8.0

The ExoPlayer constructor line returns the error **Java.Lang.ClassCastException:** 'android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser'

Why is this code is failing on these two points? The only other place I see the error from (2) is here and I am not sure of how this works.
In Short ...
Can anyone provide a working sample of C# code that can make the attribute needed for the StyledPlayerView constructor to allow a TextureView Exoplayer to be created in .NET?
Thanks for any help.

If they have a constructor accepting only XML you need XML or another constructor.

Constructor doesn't accept XML. Constructor accepts Android.Util.IAttributeSet which can apparently be made from an XML file if you load one from somewhere. I am looking for a working C#/.NET method to do this. And if one can do so, why not create the XML file programmatically as well in the C#? That is what I would like to do. Then you don't have to worry about the complexity of saving and loading a tiny 5 line XML file as well. Thanks.

After further research there is no way to do this in .NET except:

Create XML file named "test.xml" in Resources\layout
Copy paste into it:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
    android:layout_width= "match_parent"
    android:layout_height= "match_parent" />


Run code in MainActivity.cs:

XmlReader xmlResource = this.Resources.GetXml(Resource.Layout.test);
xmlResource.Read();
Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributes = Android.Util.Xml.AsAttributeSet(xmlResource);
Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.UI.StyledPlayerView styledPlayerView = new(this, attributes); 

This does work. But there is no way to programmatically create the XML whether in Kotlin or C#. It must be pre-stored in Resources and loaded from there.
This seems to be just bad Android design.

Class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView is deprecated; use androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView instead. And constructing a view from code also works differently then you might imagine (the XML is being processed and merely provides a reference to the class). The documentation would provide all the relevant attribute-names which one can pass into the constructor, otherwise located below the app namespace in XML. One basically does not need any XML to construct a View, but still somehow needs to indicate where the component shall appear in the layout.

Thanks, I am aware of the deprecation, but we don't have that yet commonly in .NET/MAUI. For example, CommunityToolkit which is MAUI's Exoplayer implementation still uses the old StyledPlayerView: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/51dc63a7642370849e413d87072b668fa022e303/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement/Views/MediaManager.android.cs#L37 EIther way, this doesn't change the question. The ExoPlayer works the same way to my knowledge still. I still need a way to specify the TextureView as the target via the attributes in the constructor given. Can you clarify how to do this?

That's definitely attribute surface_type, while the problem is that there's getter getVideoSurfaceView(), but there is no setter - which means the reference can only be passed along with AttributeSet.

Yes, I understand that. That is my question. How do we create the IAttributeSet object in C# with the attribute surface_type="texture_view" inside it so I can pass that into the constructor? Sorry if my question was unclear. Can you provide an example of code to create this attribute object that the constructor can take?

In .NET/MAUI the attributes apparently need to be mapped (so an Android example might not help much; it's just key/value pairs): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0

Thanks Martin, but you are linking to the "MAUI level" code which is not relevant here. Handlers (what you linked to) are a MAUI construction for dealing with the platform based code. What I am discussing is purely Android code running in C#. Ie. Whether MAUI or not. Ie. If you go Visual Studio > File > New > Android Application you will get a pure .NET Android project (no MAUI) and the same question will apply (ie. this is not directly a MAUI question but rather an Android .NET question).

Just look, there is no such class android.util.AttributeSet: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/tree/main/src/Mono.Android ...therefore I think Java-Interop is the only way to pass any customization.

This is a general .NET Android issue. If you go Visual Studio > File > New > Android Application, you can find Android.Util.IAttributeSet is immediately accessible directly in there the second you make the project. But again, I don't know how to make the specific object for the constructor with the needed TextureView target set inside it.

Also found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.util.iattributeset?view=net-android-34.0 ...this basically suggests to use XML (that's why there are only getters, but no settters): android.content.res.Resources.Theme#obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet, int[], int, int) Resources.Theme.obtainStyledAttributes() ...which returns TypedArray.

Thanks. So I am looking for a C# way to (1) create the 3-5 lines of XML I need programmatically, and (2) create the IAttributeSet attribute needed to contain it. Any thoughts on how this can be done? The link there does not suggest this is not possible.
